# How do I convert this raw SQL query into a Laravel Eloquent ORM query?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I've been trying to convert a raw sql query to a Laravel Eloquent ORM query and I'm stuck.

```
                SELECT *
                FROM   transaction_history
                                   WHERE  type = 'debit'
                                   AND 
                                   (
                                        description not in ('Premium Membership Balance Top Up', 'Sign Up Bonus')
                                        OR
                                        description in ('Premium Membership Balance Top Up', 'Sign Up Bonus') and extra_details is not null
                                   )
```

I just started working on a Laravel project a couple weeks ago..my brain cells have exceeded their capacity by this time of day...and I have no idea where to even start. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a `TransactionHistory` eloquent model representing `transaction_history` table, you can try to use `where` clauses with logical parameter grouping to generate the desired query.

You can check the generated sql query by replacing `get()` with `toSql()` and then dumping the output `dd($records)`;

```php
$records = TransactionHistory::query()
    ->where('type', 'debit')
    ->where(function($query) {
        $query->whereNotIn(
            'description', 
            ['Premium Membership Balance Top Up', 'Sign Up Bonus']
        ->orWhere(function($query) {
            $query->whereIn(
                'description', 
                ['Premium Membership Balance Top Up', 'Sign Up Bonus']
            )
            ->whereNotNull('extra_details');
        });
    })
    ->get();
```

[Laravel 9.x Docs - Queries Logical Grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#logical-grouping)

Answer (score 0):

You need use Raw Expressions Query Builder in laravel eloquent ORM.

Visit laravel doc => [Raw Expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#raw-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [raw query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#raw-expressions) and just paste your query.
But the best way should be to create [Models](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#generating-model-classes) (think as table) and link those models with [relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships) (like foreign key).
Also, to get started, this [tool](https://jjlabajo.github.io/SQLtoEloquent/) can helps you to convert your query to a more laravel friendly query